# How to set value to Java bean from FTL in Jive

Tags: java, struts2, struts, freemarker, jive

I am new to jive as well as freemarker

I tried following approach like we did in Struts

```xml
<input size=40 name="bvProperties.fileBasedQueueLocation" 
            type="text" value="${badgeVilleProperties.fileBasedQueueLocation!''}" style="float: right;"/>
```

that need set value of `fileBasedQueueLocation` variable available in `bvProperties` bean available in action.

I have also created setter as well as getter method for `bvProperties` in action.

Comment: What a version of Struts?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you should try:

```xml
<input size=40 name="bvProperties.fileBasedQueueLocation" 
            type="text" value="${(badgeVilleProperties.fileBasedQueueLocation)!}" style="float: right;"/>
```

Comment: yes that's correct we need to use that syntax but here we are setting value to ftl page but i need to set value in java bean....

Comment: Can you show what is generated and which tool is used?